# Proper Oracle data type for Java Object

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using Hibernate, and I want one of my column to be mapped into Java `Object`, something like so..

```
@Column(name="SPECIAL_COLUMN")
public Object getSpecialColumn() {
    ....
}
```

The `Object` could be `Integer`, `BigDecimal`, `String`, or `Date`. How do I map this to Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Integer, BigDecimal, Date, and String all implements Serializable, I ended up using `Serializable` in Java and `BLOB` in Oracle.., like so..

```
@Column(name="SPECIAL_COLUMN")
public Serializable getSpecialColumn() {
    ....
}
```